# Installing NVIDIA Container Toolkit for docker installation in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, nvidia

I am trying to install docker on Ubuntu 20.04. I have followed the instructions from [here](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_20.04&p=nvidia&f=2) (or even [here](https://illya13.github.io/RL/tutorial/2020/04/27/installing-tensorflow-in-docker-on-ubuntu-20.html)) which at some point lead to the creation of a `nvidia-docker.list` file (in order to install NVIDIA Container Toolkit):

```
# curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu20.04/nvidia-docker.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list

# cat nvidia-docker.list
deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
#deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
#deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/experimental/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
```

I have checked the actual [file](https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/nvidia-docker.list) in the site and it's identical to the ubuntu 18.04 version.

That means it only contains entries from Ubuntu 18.04. Should this be the case? And if so, are there gonna be any compatibility issues? Should I continue and follow the instructions? Are they going to be updated later for example?